# Nginx closing TCP stream connections

Tags: tcp, nginx

We have this configuration where nginx (via openresty) is used to reroute a tcp stream coming from our upstream provider to our downstream consumer.

upstream -> Openresty(nginx) -> downstream

In the current state, Nginx seems to always send `FIN, ACK` packets at regular intervals (every 10 minutes when the channel is idle, for most of our channels. Since it sends these packets both upstream and downstream, both of these tcp streams are closed, and need to be brought up again, with SYN packets.

Is there a way to keep the tcp-stream always open, and never close it? Or atleast, change settings such that the disconnect/connect happens at much larger intervals.

[Packet capture to illustrate the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUwB3.jpg)